# jQuery with ASP.NET WebForms - disabling textboxes

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-1.3

Another jQuery noob question - what am I doing wrong??

I have some HTML markup rendered by ASP.NET 3.5 webforms which looks like this:

```
<input id="ctl01_cphContent_pnlBasicInfo_chkRC" 
       type="checkbox" name="ctl01$cphContent$pnlBasicInfo$chkRC" />
<label for="ctl01_cphContent_cntPromos_pnlBasicInfo_chkRC">Recurrent Charges</label>

<span id="ctl01_cphContent_cntPromos_pnlBasicInfo_lblPromoValidFor" 
      class="rcPromo">Validity:</span>

<span class="rcPromo">
   <input id="ctl01_cphContent_pnlBasicInfo_rbnDiscountValidFor" 
          type="radio" name="ctl01$cphContent$pnlBasicInfo$discountValidFor" 
          value="rbnDiscountValidFor" checked="checked" />
   <label for="ctl01_cphContent_cntPromos_pnlBasicInfo_rbnDiscountValidFor">valid for</label>
</span>
<span class="rcPromo">
   <input id="ctl01_cphContent_pnlBasicInfo_rbnDiscountValidUntil" 
          type="radio" name="ctl01$cphContent$pnlBasicInfo$discountValidFor" 
          value="rbnDiscountValidUntil" />
   <label for="ctl01_cphContent_cntPromos_pnlBasicInfo_rbnDiscountValidUntil">valid until</label>
</span>

<input name="ctl01$cphContent$pnlBasicInfo$txtDiscountMonths" type="text"
       id="ctl01_cphContent_pnlBasicInfo_txtDiscountMonths" 
       class="textbox" class="rcPromo" originalValue="" style="width:30px;" />
<span id="ctl01_cphContent_cntPromos_pnlBasicInfo_lblMonths" class="rcPromo"></span>

<input name="ctl01$cphContent$pnlBasicInfo$txtDiscountUntil" type="text" 
       id="ctl01_cphContent_pnlBasicInfo_txtDiscountUntil" 
       class="textbox" class="rcPromo" originalValue="" style="width:150px;" />
```

- I have a checked "chkRC" which I want to trap and use to enable/disable other UI controls
- I have a number of labels, input (type=radio) and input (type=text) UI controls. These are all marked with the "rcPromo" dummy CSS class
- I have a CSS class called "textbox" for the normal textbox and "textboxDisabled" for the disabled state of the textbox, in an externally referenced CSS file, that work OK (when used in server-side code, that is)

What I'm trying to accomplish in jQuery is this: when the "chkRC" checkbox is disabled, I want to disable all relevant UI controls.

My jQuery looks like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#<%= chkRC.ClientID %>").click(function() {
            $('.rcPromo > :label').toggleClass('dimmed');

            if (this.checked) {
                $('.rcPromo').removeAttr('disabled');
                $('.rcPromo .textboxDisabled').addClass('textbox').removeClass('textboxDisabled');
            }
            else {
                $('.rcPromo > :input').removeAttr('checked');
                $('.rcPromo .textbox').addClass('textboxDisabled').removeClass('textbox');
                $('.rcPromo').attr('disabled', true);
            }
        });
    });
```

It works fine for the labels and the radiobuttons - but I just can't get it to work with the textboxes - they just stay the same all around, nothing changes (they don't get disabled and they don't change their appearance to indicate that they're disabled, either).

I don't understand this - I do see several (a few more than in the sample) textboxes, which are `<input type="text">` in HTML, and they do have the `class="rcPromo"` and `class="textbox"` on them - so why doesn't jQuery find and update those?

Any ideas?

Marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a way to augment the css class names that are assigned to controls from the skin file (phoenix is correct, the class names need to be added in the same attribute).

I can think of a few workarounds though:

--> You can wrap all the textboxes you want disabled in a div with a given class:

```
<div class="disable_textbox"><asp:textbox id="".../></div>
```

and then disable them by selecting:

```
$('.disable_textbox input').attr('disabled', true);
```

--> You can include character strings in the ID of the textboxes you want disabled:

```
<asp:textbox id="txtDiscountUntil_DisableMe" ... />
```

and then disable them like so:

```
$("input[id*='DisableMe']").attr('disabled', true);
```

--> You can add a custom attribute to your textbox:

```
txtDiscountUntil.Attributes.Add("disableme", "true");
```

and then disable them like so:

```
$("input[disableme='true']").attr('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Thanks - I'll see which method for the best for me!

Comment: Thanks for the tips - I'll probably go with the specific string postfix for my textboxes to clearly make them stand out. Sounds like it should work!

Comment: FYI, played around a bit more with getting the class attribute on the rendered textbox to contain two class names. You can override the CssClass property of the textbox in the OnPreRenderComplete event, because by that time it already contains the name of the class in the .skin file, thus: txtDiscountUntil.CssClass = txtDiscountUntil.CssClass + " rcPromo";

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML markup is not the correct one.

You can't add two classes like the one in your code.

Two classes can be added like this

```
<input type="text" class="Class1 Class2" />
```

and not like

```
<input type="text" class="Class1" class="Class2" />
```

Why don't you use [hasClass](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/hasClass) to check whether the element has this class set or not?

I think you have to give this in an OR condition for the two classes.

Comment: trouble is - I can't really change this. My ".skin" file defines a "CssClass=textbox" on all <asp:Textbox> elements, and I can't remove that (otherwise our app won't look the way it looks now)

Comment: Yes, if I specify the textboxes explicitly (using $('#<%= textbox.ClientID %>'), my jQuery works nicely.