# Auto suggest with Rendering issue

Tags: html, asp.net, page-lifecycle

I have an issue in our currently running .net application. we are using autocomplete extender control associated with city textbox for city selection. Due to slow internet connection, when user uses this application with partially rendered, it is not suggesting for entered city (highlighted in red).

I have used Page_Init event for first disable the textbox, than enable it on Page_Load, but it's not working (to prevent user for enter text when the page is not loaded completely).

Is there any solution to overcome this problem?

[image]

After loaded successfully,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to disable the textboxes until the page has loaded? I am not sure if it will work like you want but have you considered using jQuery to disable the textbox? For example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310466/jquery-with-asp-net-webforms-disabling-textboxes), [here](http://codeasp.net/blogs/raghav_khunger/microsoft-net/763/jquery-how-to-enable-disable-textbox), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648901/disable-textbox-using-jquery)

Comment: or just show a message in the middle of the dialog, that still loading, and the message go way when its fully loaded.