# Disabling Controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to disable some controls on my Aspx page but can't get it working. I've tried both Javascript and JQuery so I know I must be doing something simple wrong.

Here's what I have atm and I know that it's definitely entering both functions when I want them to because I've stuck in alerts to tell me so. However the controls remain enabled always!

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function fun1(){
var input = $('#txtDocs');
input.removeAttr('disabled');
}

function fun2() {
var input = $('#txtDocs');
input.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

And the control itself;

```
<p>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDocs" runat="server"  Width="218px" 
      Height="75px" TextMode="MultiLine" MaxLength="40"/>
</p>
```

I've also tried swapping out the code in both functions for various versions of the following;

```
document.getElementById("txtDocs").enabled = true;
document.getElementById("txtDocs").attributes.enabled = true;
document.getElementById("txtDocs").disabled = false;
```

No good though. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

current code;

```
function fun1(){
alert("1 enable");
$('#txtDocs').removeAttr('disabled');
alert("2 enable");
}

function fun2() {
alert("1 disable");
$('#txtDocs').prop('disabled', true);
alert("2 disable");
}

<asp:TextBox ID="txtDocs" runat="server"  Width="218px" ClientIDMode="Static"
      Height="75px" TextMode="MultiLine" MaxLength="40"/>
```

Still no good :/ I'm only seeing `alert("1 disable")`, `alert("1 enable")` and `alert("2 enable")` so not getting through fun2...

**NOTE**

Debugged into my code and just noticed that during run time my Textbox is actually a Textarea. Any significance? Also it's ID will have the usual "ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_" tagged onto the start.

Comment: possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310466/jquery-with-asp-net-webforms-disabling-textboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannot really explain it but after spending ages trying everything here and everything I could find on the net, referencing my object like so worked;

```
document.getElementById('ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_txtDocs').disabled = false;
```

Note the lack of # before the ID. Also, I did not need the ClientIDMode as I put "ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_" before my ID.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using prop() if you're using jQuery 1.6+

```
$('#txtDocs').prop('disabled',true);
$('#txtDocs').prop('disabled',false);
```

Acoording to jQuery docs http://api.jquery.com/prop/

> The .prop() method should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the .attr() method.

Answer (score 1):

`disabled` is a binary property, not an attribute, so you need to use:

```
$('#txtDocs').prop('disabled','disabled');
$('#txtDocs').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Comment: .NET doesn't play well with IDS. It wants to own them all. Use a CSS class name instead. $('.txtDocs'), and give your element the matching css class name,

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you should be doing:

```
input.attr('disabled', true); // to disable

input.removeAttr('disabled'); // to enable
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `TextBox` ID "txtDocs" does not end up on the client like that, so javascript cannot find an element with `id="txtDocs"` You need to set the [`ClientIDMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) attribute on your TextBox control to `Static`:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDocs" runat="server" Width="218px" ClientIDMode="Static" 
   Height="75px" TextMode="MultiLine" MaxLength="40" />
```

Answer (score 0):

### Mark Up

You are missing **[ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx)**...

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDocs" runat="server" Width="218px" 
  ClientIDMode="Static" Height="75px" TextMode="MultiLine" MaxLength="40" />
```

### JavaScript

```
document.getElementById('IdOfTheTextbox').disabled = true/false;
```

### You FireBug instead to scan the issue closely